# Directive : attribute must specify a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm following this https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate but I get an error in my console :

> Error: Directive: angular-scroll-animate 'when-visible' attribute must specify a function.

**index.html**

```
     <section ng-controller="Section1Controller" >
          <div class="container" when-visible="animateElementIn" when-not-visible="animateElementOut" class="hidden">
            <h3 class="section-title">{{titresection}}</h3>
            <div class="line-section"></div>
            <div class="section-thumb"><img ng-src="../assets/images/avatar.jpg">
              <p class="section-contenue">{{paragraphe}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>   
        </section>
```

**controller.html**

```
apps.controller('Section1Controller', function ($scope) {

      $scope.titresection="Développeur frontend & backend";
      $scope.image='../assets/images/avatar.jpg';
      $scope.lefttitle=" 2016";
      $scope.paragraphe="éveloppeur frontend, qui développe des sites vitrines sous WordPress et des dernières techniques web : HTML5/CSS3, jQuery, jQuery UI,NodeJs,AngularJs.";

     $scope.animateElementIn = function($el) {
    $el.removeClass('hidden');
    $el.addClass('animated fadeInUp'); // this example leverages animate.css classes
  };

  $scope.animateElementOut = function($el) {
    $el.addClass('hidden');
    $el.removeClass('animated fadeInUp'); // this example leverages animate.css classes
  };
/*

  });
```

Comment: Have you looked at that project's [issue log](https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate/issues/7)?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I have added a jsfiddle. see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jgh9yumx/). It works fine.  Your template looks fine. There must be mistake somewhere else. I hope  you have included animate.css. If you could share a jsfiddle/plunker of your code, it will help us to solve the problem.

I scrolled through the code of `angular-scroll-animate` and found out that `when-visible` and `when-not-visible` are actually references to functions.

```
controller: ['$scope', function(scope) {
        if (!scope.whenVisible || !angular.isFunction(scope.whenVisible())) {
          throw new Error('Directive: angular-scroll-animate \'when-visible\' attribute must specify a function.');
        }

        if (scope.whenNotVisible && !angular.isFunction(scope.whenNotVisible())) {
          throw new Error('Directive: angular-scroll-animate \'when-not-visible\' attribute must specify a function.');
        }
        else if (!scope.whenNotVisible) {
          scope.whenNotVisible = function() {
            return angular.noop;
          };
        }

        if (scope.delayPercent) {

          var delayPercent = parseFloat(scope.delayPercent);

          if (!angular.isNumber(delayPercent) || (delayPercent < 0 || delayPercent > 1)) {
            throw new Error('Directive: angular-scroll-animate \'delay-percent\' attribute must be a decimal fraction between 0 and 1.');
          }
        }
    }],
```

**Below will not work**
You need to use

```
  <div class="container" when-visible="animateElementIn()" when-not-visible="animateElementOut()" class="hidden">
```

Because they are functions

Comment: Not working please see https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate for understand what i need

Comment: @sabrine "Not working" is the absolute least helpful thing you could say, except for "banana". Please describe what is not working.

Comment: @JDB i said i'm using this https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate and when i run my app it's not showing my data and get error Error: Directive: angular-scroll-animate 'when-visible' attribute must specify a function.

Comment: @sabrine Can you add a plunker if possible? Because, I suspect that controller is  not binded properly in that case

Comment: Naga-Sandeep JDB
sabrine is right, the documentation and the examples show exactly what is stated in the question..
@sabrine may be you are making some other mistake, as the example on the repository works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not saying that sabrine is wrong... I'm saying the "not working" is not a helpful thing to say. "No difference" is way more helpful.

Comment: updated answer with a fiddle. It actually is not a function call.